# How do I Moq IFindFluent so this call to ToListAsync works?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mongodb-.net-driver

I am unit testing a wrapper to the MongoDB C# driver. I have this line of code:

```
Collection.Find(predicate).ToListAsync();
```

Where `Collection` is of type `IMongoCollection<T>` and `Find(predicate)` returns an instance implementing `IFindFluent<T, T>`. `ToListAsync()` is an extension to turn the results into a list, I assume.

I am attempting to write unit tests, and I am stumped on handling this. I can't make a wrapper class because that's what I'm working on. I would prefer to either make it so `ToListAsync()` returns a created list OR to mock the `Find()` to return something that can be made a list of.

Comment: This answered here on this post [Moq IFindFluent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43203657/how-to-mock-ifindfluent-interface/59769546#59769546)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wound up making a little abstraction layer for this, since I couldn't find anything suitable and asking for help yielded no answers.

I created an interface/implementation pair called `AppCollection` specifically to handle the MongoDB interface. `IAppCollection` would have a method for `IAppCollection.ToList(predicate)`, and the `AppCollection` would run the `Collection.Find(predicate).ToListAsync();` call, returning the list. Later, it was a trivial matter to mock the `IAppCollection` to make sure the right calls were being made. While I couldn't test the predicates in native LINQ, I could at least compile the predicates and compare them to passing/failing objects.

Comment: I am struggling with mocking IFindFluent as well and came across your post. Would you be able to provide me your implementation of IAppCollection interface in order to put more light on your solution? 
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3):

If anyone would struggle with getting it to work,  what I did to mock `Find()` method was:

```
[TestFixture]
class QueryControllerTests
{
    private IOptions<MongoSettings> _mongoSettings;
    private QueryController _queryController;
    private Mock<IFakeMongoCollection> _fakeMongoCollection;
    private Mock<IFindFluent<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>> _fakeCollectionResult;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _fakeMongoCollection = new Mock<IFakeMongoCollection>();
        _fakeCollectionResult = new Mock<IFindFluent<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>>();

    }
}
```

where `IFakeMongoCollection` is:

```
public interface IFakeMongoCollection : IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>
{
    IFindFluent<BsonDocument, BsonDocument> Find(FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> filter, FindOptions options);
}
```

Comment: This looks like it has potential, but could you provide a little more context on how to use the mock?